# Can you tell HHVM to treat a file as php even if the extension is abc

Tags: php, lighttpd, hhvm

Trying to run HHVM concurrently with our current php configuration on lighttpd based on the domain...for example ewxample.hhvm.com 
Our code base uses non-standard file extensions for all of our files and whenver the file is passed to HHVM it doesn't parse it and serves it as a static file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add it to the list of php file extensions, using the `hhvm.php_file.extensions` INI array.

```
hhvm.php_file.extensions[abc] = abc
```